# Python: Measuring a particle length in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am a python beginner.

I am working on calculating the length of a particle from 100s of images. I have an example image below.
[image]
Is there a way to use the graph as a reference to calculate the length of particle? Is it through OpenCV?

I would only need the length of the particles in microns no need of area or any statistical analysis.

Thanks in advance.

I looked through lot of examples online but not successful in finding a script which can do a simple length finding.
I am pretty new to python programming and it will be great if you can provide me the script.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].

Comment: If you know the range in the graph in your units of microns and you know the size of the image colored area (threshold on that color and get the bounding box), then you have a calibration between pixels and microns.  So all you then need to do is threshold on the particle and fit an ellipse to it. From the ellipse you get the major and minor radii (half diameters) as well as the rotation angle.